# Problem with bibliography (BibTex) natbib package and Bib Style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, texstudio

For my thesis I'm working with TeXStudio and I tried to include my bibliography in my document. I used BibTeX for my bibliography and saved it in a `.bib` file, but I can't seem to make it work properly. When I use `\usepackage{natbib}`, I get an error message saying

> ! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year
>   citations.

And whatever style I use, it keeps the plain style...
Someone knows what I did wrong?

Here my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english,german,latin,italian,spanish,russian,greek}

\begin{document}
text
\section{Bibliographie}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{roumain}
\end{document}
```

Example of my bibliography:

```
@mvbook{SMFC,
    author = {SMFC = Academia RPR, Institutul de lingvistica din Bucuresti},
    title = {Institutul de lingvistica din Bucuresti, Studii \c{s}i materiale privitoare la formarea cuvintelor în limba român\u{a}},
    date = {vol I, 1959 ; II, 1960 ; III, 1962 ; IV, 1967 ; V, 1969 ; VI, 1972},
    editor = {Editura Academiei},
    volumes = {6},
    location = {Bucarest},
}
@inbook{Asan-PsaltHur,
    author = {Asan, Finuţa},
    title = {Derivarea cu sufixe şi prefixe în Psaltirea Hurmuzaki},
    booktitle = {SMFC},
    date = {1959},
    bookauthor = {Academia RPR, Institutul de lingvistica din Bucuresti},   editor = {Editura Academiei},
    location = {Bucarest},
    volume = {1},
    volumes = {6},
    pages = {203-212}
}     
@book{Popescu-Formarea,
    author = {Popescu Marin, Magdalena (coord.)},
    title = {Formarea cuvintelor în limba română din secolele al XVI lea – al XVIII lea},
    date = {2007},
    editor = {Editura Academiei},
    location = {Bucarest},
}
```

[image]

Comment: You will have to replace `\bibliographystyle{acm}` with something that is natbib compatible. Btw: You are using xelatex or lualatex, so dont't load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Right, in my file I put an % in front of the inputenc package. Actually I tried that and it's not working. When I use the style plainnat.bst it compiles, but other styles that should work like abbrvnat don't. I still get the same error message : "! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations."

Comment: Have you tried option `numbers`?

Comment: By the way, with the current setup, i.e. `abbrvnat`, it works fine. It is an author year style.

Comment: Your example doesn't contain any \cite command. So I doubt that it shows your output. Beside this: If you change the style, delete the bbl and then compile anew (including a bibtex call). Besides this: Be careful with accented chars in your bib. Unlike biblatex/biber, natbib+bibtex can't handle utf8 so they can break.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your code I can see some problems.

For example should package `hyperref` be the last called package!
The documentation of package `natbib` can you read by typing `texdoc natbib` on your console/terminal.  There are the styles listed you can use with `natbib` and which styles and field names are supported.

To give you a starting point I changed your MWE, deleted not needed package calls for this problem, changed the order of package calls and added the missing informations for field `year` and `publisher` to your bib file (btw package `filecontents` is only used to have bib file and TeX code in one compilable MWE).

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{SMFC,
  author    = {{SMFC = Academia RPR, Institutul de lingvistica din Bucuresti}},
  title     = {Institutul de lingvistica din Bucuresti, Studii \c{s}i 
               materiale privitoare la formarea cuvintelor în limba român\u{a}},
  note      = {vol I, 1959 ; II, 1960 ; III, 1962 ; IV, 1967 ; V, 1969 ; VI, 1972},
  year      = {1972},
  editor    = {Editura Academiei},
  publisher = {UNKNOWN},
  volumes   = {6},
  location  = {Bucarest},
}
@inbook{Asan-PsaltHur,
  author     = {Asan, Finuţa},
  title      = {Derivarea cu sufixe şi prefixe în Psaltirea Hurmuzaki},
  booktitle  = {SMFC},
  year       = {1959},
  bookauthor = {Academia RPR, Institutul de lingvistica din Bucuresti}, 
  editor     = {Editura Academiei},
  publisher  = {UNKNOWN},
  location   = {Bucarest},
  volume     = {1},
  volumes    = {6},
  pages      = {203--212},
}
@book{Popescu-Formarea,
  author    = {Popescu Marin, Magdalena (coord.)},
  title     = {Formarea cuvintelor în limba română din secolele al XVI lea – al XVIII lea},
  year      = {2007},
  editor    = {Editura Academiei},
  publisher = {UNKNOWN},
  location  = {Bucarest},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec} % utf-8 encoding!
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english,german,latin,italian,spanish,russian,greek}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
text \cite{Asan-PsaltHur} \nocite{*}
\section{Bibliographie}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} % plainnat abbrvnat
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Now if you compile you will get three warnings like this:

[image: three resulting warnings]

As you can see the warning is pretty clear (same with the warnings you got with your original code): you can not use author and editor both.  Please rework your bib file.  I also changed your undefined `@mvbook` to `@book`.

At last three tips:

- `SMFC = Academia RPR, Institutul de lingvistica din Bucuresti` is an unusual entry for an author, better would be to place the acronym in the text and use the complete name. But your given name for author is an institution, as I can see.  So better use it as editor ...
- `Studii \c{s}i` should be in an utf-8 encoded file changed. Please change all tex substitutions for special characters with cedilie etc. to the corresponding original utf-8 letter.
- You need a field `year` to be style-conform, so in the case of your first entry `SMFC` I would use field `note={vol I, 1959 ; II, 1960 ; III, 1962 ; IV, 1967 ; V, 1969 ; VI, 1972},` instead your date field.

Comment: The author of the SFMC entry is clearly best taken to be a "corporate" author. Hence, use an extra pair of braces: `author    = {{SMFC = Academia RPR, Institutul de lingvistica din Bucuresti}},`.